# How to efficiently find the index column of the leftest non null value of a row in a numpy matrix?

Tags: python, numpy

I was wondering if there is a quick way to find the index of the leftest non null value of each row a numpy matrix.

Lest's say I have this:

```
data = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, 10,      1],
                 [np.nan, 30,      50,      np.nan],
                 [40,      np.nan, np.nan, 5],
                 [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 10]])
```

I would like to return the indexes of 10, 30, 40 and 10 respectively, i.e. 2, 1, 0 and 3.

The follwing works but it is not exactly efficient (e.g. the loop inside the `fn` function is slow):

```
def fn(row):
    for idx, v in enumerate(row):
         if not np.isnan(v):
              return idx
np.apply_along_axis(fn, 1, data)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the boolean array of non-nulls with `np.isnan` and then get first ones in each row with `argmax(1)` for those indices and finally index into input array -

```
In [19]: idx = (~np.isnan(data)).argmax(1)

In [20]: idx
Out[20]: array([2, 1, 0, 3])

In [21]: data[np.arange(len(idx)), idx]
Out[21]: array([10., 30., 40., 10.])
```

Comment: Could you explain why we use `argmax` to take the first of the indices? We simply need the first of the `True` values in a mask, why `argmax`?

Comment: @SashaTsukanov `argmax` returns the indices of the first occurence of a maximum value along an axis.  In a boolean array, that means `True`